# SQL - find all stores that do not stock a product that was made after January 1st, 2003

Tags: sql

I want to find all stores that do not stock a product that was made after January 1st, 2003.

I currently have stores all with distinct names. Some stock products made after January 1st, 2003, some stock products made before and some with stock products that are made both before and after.

What I have tried is

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.name FROM Store s
    WHERE s.pcode NOT IN (
        SELECT s2.pcode
        FROM StockInfo s2
        WHERE s2.productRelease BETWEEN "2003-01-01" AND NOW()
    )
```

However, this returns both stores with products made before and after the specified date and ones with products only made before the specified date.

Would someone please be able to help me with this issue.

The structure of these tables is:

**Store**:

```
ID | name  
1  | Coles  
2  | Woolworths
```

etc.

**StockInfo**:

```
ID | name       | pcode | productRelease  
1  | Coles      | 1     | "2010-03-05"  
1  | Coles      | 3     | "2001-01-01"  
2  | Woolworths | 2     | "2003-01-01"
```

etc.

Comment: @lurker thanks for the response, my problem I think is checking their entire stock. I'm not quite sure how to do that AND apply the date constraint. Because currently I'm checking each product individually and thus for stores with products before 2003 and after I'm running into trouble.

Comment: Ah right. Good question. I retracted my first comment. You can use the subquery in this case. You want all of the stores in which the collection of products made after January 1, 2003 is empty. Sorry I'm on my mobile phone so it's hard for me to elaborate at the moment... :-/

Answer (score 1):

Use `not exists`:

```
SELECT s.name
FROM Store s
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM StockInfo si
                  WHERE si.id = s.id AND
                        si.productRelease >= '2003-01-01'
                 );
```

Presumably `id` is the code for the *store*.  This should be called something more descriptive, like `storeId`, if you have control over the data model.  Similarly, `name` should not be repeated in both `store` and `stockInfo`.

In addition, `SELECT DISTINCT` should not be necessary for this query or for your version.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a suggestion.

```
SELECT  DISTINCT s.name 
FROM    Store s
JOIN    (SELECT ID
        FROM StockInfo
        GROUP BY ID
        HAVING MAX(productRelease) <= '2003-01-01') s2
ON      s.ID = s2.ID
```

(It's helpful to provide the structure and some sample data.)

Comment: Hi, this seemed to have the same effect as my original query did. I've edited the question with some sample data.

Comment: I had to guess at the column names initially.  I revised to use `id` instead of `pcode`.

Answer (score 0):

Since `StockInfo` contains the column `name` of the stores there is no need to use the table `Store`.
With `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.name FROM StockInfo s
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM StockInfo
  WHERE name = s.name AND productRelease > '2003-01-01'
)
```

Or:

```
SELECT name 
FROM StockInfo
GROUP BY name
HAVING MAX(productRelease) <= '2003-01-01'
```